# WPF RotateTransform question on offset

Tags: wpf, rotatetransform

In the following:

```
<Rectangle Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,100,0,0" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" >
<Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="30" CenterY="30"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

To rotate the rectangle on its centre I have to set the CenterX and Y to half of the Rectangle's size. Is there a way to do that in markup?

Something like CenterX="{Binding  Path=Width\2}" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set `RenderTrasformOrigin` property on the `Rectangle` itself:

```
<Rectangle Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,100,0,0" Name="rectangle2" 
           Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" 
           RenderTrasformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
<Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
    </TransformGroup>
</Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: Excellent. I knew it would be straight forward.